# If a function $F:(a, b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has a derivative in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ everywhere on $(a, b)$, is the derivative finite a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-measure

Assume that
$F^\prime(x) := \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}$ exists in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ for all $x\in(a, b)$. Is there a way to use to Vitali covering theorem to prove that $\{x\in (a, b): |F^\prime(x)|= \infty\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$? If such a proof requires $F$ to be continuous then that is fine as well. Of course I am not asking for someone to provide an entire proof here, but some ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how to prove this directly, but at the very least the conclusion is true by the [Denjoy-Young-Saks theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denjoy%E2%80%93Young%E2%80%93Saks_theorem).

Comment: I am aware of this. I might have to suffer through Saks book to find a proof, but I find it a bit difficult to read.

Comment: *suffer through Saks book to find a proof* --- A more digestible proof is Article 9 on pp. 17-19 of [**Functional Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486662896) by Riesz/Sz.-Nagy. Even more digestible is Section 3.2 on pp. 119-126 of [**Introduction to Real Functions and Orthogonal Expansions**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0195010744) by Sz.-Nagy.